# Angular - Download directly PDF from Storage (without view)

Tags: angular, firebase, download, storage

I am trying to Download in Angular directly , PDF File. Withouth display , without viewing.  But it is not working, neither whith download , nor withouth target: "_blank"  .... Does  Someone know some solution for that??

`<button class="btn btn-sm blue-back" style="float: right"> <a href="{{file.url}}" download="{{file.name}}">Download</a> </button><span></span>`

I tried it :

`<button (click)="downloadF()">downloadFile</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this helper function:

```
export function downloadFromBlobAndFileName(blob: Blob, fileName: string): void {
    // Create a new a element and append it to the document.
    const downloadClickElement = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(downloadClickElement);

    // Create an URL that contains the blob download.
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // Set the URL on the created a element.
    // Set the name of the download to the file name of the export.
    // This should be the same as the downloaded file.
    downloadClickElement.href = url;
    downloadClickElement.download = fileName;

    // Simulate a click on the a element.
    downloadClickElement.click();

    // Revoke the object to remove it out of RAM.
    // Remove the a element to clean up the DOM.
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    downloadClickElement.remove();
}
```

The first note of [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) states that the `download` attribute only works for same-origin URLs.